# Excel VBA throws subscript out of range in office 2007 but not in office 2013

Tags: excel, vba

I have a league table spreadsheet that a user is to use to collate results from several events (results spreadsheets).  The user clicks a button to get the results from another spreadsheet, this runs the subroutine which displays the file dialog (msoFileDialogFilePicker) to get the path to the results file, the subroutine then opens the file and performs some basic checks before trying to extract the scores.
Everything seems to work fine in office 2013 (initial development environment) but when I tried to test the spreadsheet in office 2007 for compatibility (as some users may not be up to date with versions of excel), I get an error when the results spreadsheet file is opened by the vba subroutine.

I have searched through many of the answers relating vba error 9 (subscript out of range) issues but I can't seem to find an answer which would explain why there would be a problem between excel 2007 & 2013.  As I said it all works fine in Office 2013.

The error is thrown at line:-

```
If tmpWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Name <> "Gala Results" Then
```

The spelling of the worksheet name is correct and the worksheet exists in the results file etc.

```
Sub Gala1_GetResults_Click()

Dim MSG_Response, MSG_Overwrite As Integer
Dim Response, Overwrite As Boolean
Dim sumTeamA, sumTeamB, sumTeamC, sumTeamD, sumTeamE As String
Dim sht_Results, sht_Summary As Worksheet
Dim rng_ResultsTeams, rng_sumTeam, cel, rng_tmpTeams, rng_AGTeam As Range
Dim tmpWB As Workbook
Dim tmp_ScoreCol, tmp_ScoreRow, tmp_Score, tmp_TeamCol, tmp_TeamRow As 
Integer
Dim tmp_Team, tmp_Division, str_Division As String

'some code lives here to get the filename and check it hasn't been 
'previously used etc.

'open the results file
Set tmpWB = Workbooks.Open(strResultsPath)

'check the file has the correct sheet
If tmpWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Name <> "Gala Results" Then
    'sheet doesn't exist, wrong file openend
    MsgBox "Worksheet Gala Results not present in selected file," & 
vbCrLf & _
            "please check file selected is a valid gala results file.", 
vbOKOnly, "Get Results - Error"
    Exit Sub
End If
Set sht_Results = Workbooks(tmpWB.Name).Worksheets("Gala Results")
Set rng_ResultsTeams = sht_Results.Range("F17,I17,L17,O17, R17")
tmp_Division = sht_Results.Range("C10").Value

'more code lives here to extract the score values and to place them in 
'the correct location in the table
End Sub
```

Any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: What is `tmpWb` you set it open to `strResultsPath` but I can't see where that variable is defined? Is it a public variable?

Comment: This is occurring because there is no path in `Set tmpWB = Workbooks.Open(strResultsPath)` and your tmpWB is empty

Comment: Also, `tmpWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Name` name will always be `Sheet1` Are you referencing this incorrectly? Do you mean `tmpWb.Sheets(1).Name` or `Sheet1.Name`? Does a sheet named `Sheet1` exist?

Comment: Hi Tom, strResultsPath is a global string variable.

when I debug the code, in the locals window, if I navigate to tmpWB.worksheets(1).name it shows the correct "Gala Results" string..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in a comment above `tmpWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Name` will always result in `Sheet1`. I suspect you're trying to find whether the sheet `Gala Results` exist in the workbook and on your colleagues machine it is missing *but* your code is testing for whether `"Sheet1" = "Gala Results"` so it isn't detecting the sheet is missing.

The following may be a better way to approach this

```
Dim GalaResults as Worksheet

On Error Resume Next
Set GalaResults = tmpWb.Sheets("Gala Results")
On Error Goto 0

If GalaResults is Nothing Then
' .... Your code to handle the missing sheet
```

Using Error handling I set the worksheet that I want to a variable. I then test whether this variable is empty or not.

Comment: @JKelly43 Do you understand why `tmpWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Name` will always be "Sheet1"? You've referenced the sheet using the sheet name of "Sheet1" and then asked the object to return its `Name`

Comment: Problem now solved! Thnk you so much.. the error handling is much better as per your suggestion.  I also think that I mistakenly had tmpWB.Worksheets("Gala Results") instead of tmpWB.Sheets("Gala Results")..

Comment: @JKelly43 I don't think that would've made much of a difference. The only real difference between the two is `Worksheets` can only be used for Sheets that are grids and lines; Where as `Sheets` will refer to `Chart` `Sheets` as well

Comment: I understand now thanks, additionally "Sheet1" didn't exist in the results file...